# What is the origin of the expression 'pull a fast one'?

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the expression 'pull a fast one'?

> Don't try to pull a fast one on me. I'm not stupid, you know.

**pull a fast one (on somebody)** tell lies or cheat somebody, for example in order to get their money, possessions, etc; deceive somebody.

Where did the phrase 'pull a fast one' come from?

Comment: [http://wordoriginsorg.yuku.com/topic/9638/pull-a-fast-one](http://wordoriginsorg.yuku.com/topic/9638/pull-a-fast-one)  Google search to the rescue...search using "etymology" and the word/phrase you want to check.

Comment: It's interesting; however, as I understand, etymology is [off-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. It might be better to avoid asking etymology questions. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about etymology. lease consider asking this question on English Language & Usage (http://english.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's not mentioned everywhere and it's a bit difficult to find. What I find at most of the places is this - *The Dictionary of American Slang cites a use in print in 1944 but doesn't explain the origin.*

However, I got it!

> [Origin](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pull+a+fast+one): before 900; Middle English; Old English fæst  firm; cognate with Dutch vast, Old Norse fastr  firm, German fest;  akin to fast

Answer (score 1):

The answer above shows the origin of the word 'fast,' not the expression 'pull a fast one.' I googled it and found where the idiom is originated.

This expression originated in the English sport of cricket, and meant to bowl a fast ball. It probably became popular in the United States either in reference to a fast shuffle of cards or to the fastball in baseball, which usually comes
when you're not expecting it.

The explanation is cited from 
http://s3.amazonaws.com/edcanvas-uploads/307480/local/1391220521/Historical%20Fiction%20Week%203.pdf